Temporarily map a named docker volume on the host
I have a named volume called foo. I can find its physical location on the host via docker volume inspect foo which gives me something like /var/lib/docker/volumes/foo/_data. I want to be able to rsync files from and to that directory on the host (i.e from and to that named volume) but I want to avoid doing that directly on that path which will also require me using root.
Is there a clean way to temporarilly map that foo named volume on the host's /tmp/foo path so I can do whatever I want to be doing and then removing that mapping?

If it's important to be able to directly manipulate the files, a Docker bind mount might be a better choice than a named volume.  Use /tmp/foo:/container/path as the mount option and whatever is in the host in /tmp/foo will be visible in the container; it should bidirectionally sync between the container and host.

@DavidMaze this works, but this would also mean that these files would not appear in any docker volume, is that right?

True; is there a reason it would specifically need to be in a named volume?

@DavidMaze for consistency. I want to be able to grab the data from all named volumes together with all docker compose yml files and move to another host.

I didn't find a way to map the volume to the host so I could rsync.
The next possible clean way was to start a container, map the host's ssh key and known_hosts into /root/.ssh/, install rsync, and rsync from there.
docker run \
       --rm \
       --name temp-container-for-volume-rsync \
       --volume foo:/vol \
       --volume ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh \
       alpine \
       sh -c 'apk add --no-cache openssh-client rsync && rsync -avzi /vol user@example.com:/tmp/'

